# Кроссбраузерность и position:absolute

Tags: html, css

http://hotel.adr.com.ua/
Если открыть в хроме, то так должен выглядеть сайт, но в опере и мозиле в первом блоке есть блок с `position:absolute`  и он куда то исчезает в опере и мозиле, с `z-index` уже игрался не получилось, что нужно добавить? Спасибо!
P. S. проблемный блок называется `hotel__pres`

Comment: Попробуй добавить родительскому блоку `hotel__pres` `position: relative;`

Comment: возьмите за правило всегда добавлять `left` и `top` блокам, которым выставляете `position:absolute`. Иначе их положение не предопределено. Хром, чаще всего, показывает ожидаемо, а вот с остальными всегда беда.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавь этому блоку:

```
.hotel__pres {
  ...
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Иначе он теряется (прячется за границами)